# How to inject beans in the main class of a SpringBoot & JavaFx application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javafx, javabeans

I am starting up with JavaFX and I would like to integrate it with Spring Boot.

I have followed this blog which is describing how this is done:
https://better-coding.com/javafx-spring-boot-gradle-project-setup-guide-and-test/

It has these methods, among other things:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
@Override
public void init() throws Exception {
    springContext = SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class);
    fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
}
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/fxml/sample.fxml"));
    rootNode = fxmlLoader.load();

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    Scene scene = new Scene(rootNode, 800, 600);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

As you can see, the `init()` and `start()` methods introduce a hard dependency between my main class and the `FXMLLoader` and `Scene` classes. So I would like to remove these dependencies and therefore I have created a bean for the `FXMLLoader` (to start with) in my `AppConfig` class:

```
@Bean
public FXMLLoader fxmlLoader() {
    return new FXMLLoader();
}
```

And then I autowired it in my main class (autowire on property) and removed the instantiation of the `FXMLLoader` from the `init()` method:

```
@Autowired
private FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;
```

When I run the application, it fails with `NullPointerException` because the `fxmlLoader` is null.
As an alternative, I am getting the bean directly from the context with the `getBean()` method:

```
@Override
public void init() throws Exception {
    springContext = SpringApplication.run(SpringFxApplication.class);
    fxmlLoader = springContext.getBean(FXMLLoader.class);
    fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
}
```

Seeing as this is considered to be a bad practice, how could I inject the bean in my main class?

**FULL CODE:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.testpackage")
public class SpringFxApplication extends Application {

    @Autowired
    private FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        springContext = SpringApplication.run(SpringFxApplication.class);
        //fxmlLoader = springContext.getBean(FXMLLoader.class);
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/fxml/sample.fxml"));
        Parent rootNode = fxmlLoader.load();

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootNode, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        springContext.stop();
    }
}

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public FXMLLoader fxmlLoader() {
        return new FXMLLoader();
    }
}
```

Comment: not 100% sure anymore, but i think you need to add something like @ComponentScan({"com.mypackage"}) and @Configuration. Or Spring doesn´t know that there is a bean somewhere. See here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning and/or here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire

Comment: most probably something wrong in the code you are not showing - [mcve] please :)

Comment: @kleopatra Full code added.

Comment: @djnose Already did that. Please see the full code that I added.

Comment: Spring creates its own instance of `SpringFxApplication` separate from the instance that is created by the JavaFX runtime. The latter instance is the one which has its life-cycle methods (i.e. `init()`, `start(Stage)`, `stop()`) invoked. Is there a way to manually put an instance of an object into a context and then have it perform dependency injection? I believe such a thing is possible in CDI but I don't know about Spring.

Comment: Afaik singleton is the default scope. You'll probably get into trouble with this later, since `FXMLLoader` cannot (or should not) be reused.